# C# having problems with using global variables

Tags: c#, arrays, function, for-loop, procedure

So, I have finished majority of my code but one criteria required me to use a Procedure. So, when i decided to use a procedure i encountered several of problems. The main issue was that the variables which i have included in the first method(`Generate Number` and `number`) wont show up in my other methods.So can i make these variables global so that they work in all of my methods or is there another alternative solution to this problem?

**Note:** This is not my full code its just a piece out of it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random GenerateNumber = new Random();
        int[] number = new int[6];
        Generating();
        Ordering();
    }

    static void Generating()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Stage 1 : 6 random numbers have been generated:\n");
        for (int c = 0; c < number.Length; c++)
        {
            if (number[c] == 0)
            {
                number[c] = GenerateNumber.Next(1, 50);
                Console.Write("Random number " + (c + 1) + " = " + number[c] + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    static void Ordering()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
        {
            Array.Sort(number);
            Console.Write("Number " + (i + 1) + " = " + number[i] + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make them static members of the `Program` class.

Comment: Google for c#  variable scopes

Comment: You don't want *globals* you want to pass *parameters*, see [Passing Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters)

Comment: Im new to programming and i didn't understand what u meant by that.

Comment: Ok i will check pass parameters.

Comment: Please note you have your Array.Sort call inside a loop. That way you will sort the array as many times as the length of the array. Is that what you want? Check my answer below for suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make them global is easiest but as said above, not the best way.

```
class Program
{
    static Random GenerateNumber = new Random();
    static int[] number = new int[6];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Generating();
        Ordering();
    }
```

Better to use parameters

```
class Program
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random GenerateNumber = new Random();
        int[] number = new int[6];
        Generating(GenerateNumber, number);
        Ordering(number);
    }

    static void Generating(Random generateNumber, int[] number)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Stage 1 : 6 random numbers have been generated:\n");
        for (int c = 0; c < number.Length; c++)
        {
            if (number[c] == 0)
            {
                number[c] = generateNumber.Next(1, 50);
                Console.Write("Random number " + (c + 1) + " = " + number[c] + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    static void Ordering(int[] number)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
        {
            Array.Sort(number);
            Console.Write("Number " + (i + 1) + " = " + number[i] + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            Random GenerateNumber = new Random();
            int[] number = new int[6];

            int[] generatedNumber = p.Generating(GenerateNumber, number);
            p.Ordering(generatedNumber);
        }

        public int[] Generating(Random GenerateNumber, int[] number)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Stage 1 : 6 random numbers have been 
            generated:\n");
            for (int c = 0; c < number.Length; c++)
            {
                if (number[c] == 0)
                {
                    number[c] = GenerateNumber.Next(1, 50);
                    Console.Write("Random number " + (c + 1) + " = " + number[c] 
                    + "\n");
                }
            }
            return number;
        }

        public void Ordering(int[] number)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
            {
                Array.Sort(number);
                Console.Write("Number " + (i + 1) + " = " + number[i] + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/3K6P54

Answer (score 0):

If you have more methods like those working with your array of numbers then I'd suggest you create a CLASS that encapsulates the behaviors that you want. Something alone the lines of:

```
public class MyNumberArrayWithMethods
{
    public int[] Numbers { get; set; }
    public Action<int, int> Writer { get; set; }

    //parametric constructor        
    public MyNumberArrayWithMethods(int length, Action<int, int> writer = null)
    {
        Numbers = new int[length];
        Writer = writer;
    }

    public void Generating(int lowerBound = 1, int upperBound = 50)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < Number.Length; c++)
        {
            if (Number[c] == 0)
            {
                Number[c] = GenerateNumber.Next(lowerBound, upperBound);
                if(Writer != null)
                    Writer(c, Number[c])
            }
        }
    }

    public void Ordering()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Array.Sort(Number);
        if(Writer != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < Number.Length; i++)
                Writer(i, Number[i]);
    }

    //... all other methods that work with "Number" array should go here
}
```

and then in your main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action<int, int> writer = 
        (pos, num) => { Console.Write("Number " + (pos + 1) + " = " + num + "\n"); }
    var MyCtrl = new MyNumberArrayWithMethods(6, writer);
    MyCtrl.Generating();
    Ordering();
}
```

Please notice how I moved your Array.Sort call outside the loop. If you leave it inside you will sort the array as many times as the length of the array and I'm guessing you don't want that.